# How to reuse a layout in other fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using a `Navigation Drawer Activity`. When I made two `fragments`, I noticed that their layout was the same. The difference is that pressing the `button` executes a different method for each `fragment`. But the other `buttons` do the same thing on the two `fragments`. How do I reuse the layout and java code for the `fragments` and be able to specify a method to be executed on each fragment, knowing that it will need `View` access?

Comment: We can more easily answer your question with concrete suggestions if you show some code that you have currently for the two fragments.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create two different fragment classes that load the same XML layout and assign the click handler for the button programmatically.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. Create two classes for two fragments and inflate the same layout in them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use visibility of the button.use same xml for both fragment instead of one button use two, then in fragment check which fragment is in view then change the visibility.Gone of the not needed button for the activity. if you are using databindng then do different task for two button in viewmodel that will do the rest of your button task

Comment: OP is using two fragments, not two activities. Could you please re-adjust your answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can set a Boolean (fals is the first "fragment", true the second). Then you can use a check in witch "fragment" you are and execute the code.

```
if(true){
executeFirstButtonUse()
}else{
executeSecondButtonUse()
}
```

Then U wil have 1 fragmen, 1 view, (1 viewModel).

I u coud provide more info or code I could provide more detail or an other method.

Comment: That seems to me like an anti-pattern. OP should just inflate the same layout in two different Fragment classes, just like in @Code-Apprentice answer.

Comment: Didn't know this was possible. Well thank you for this.